# Como juntar três ou mais arquivos CSVs com algo do tipo PROCV e concatenando certas colunas

Tags: python, pandas

Arquivo1.csv

```
Codigo  Nome    Catego  Geral                   Model   Ano
A1      JOGO    LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF    2017
A2      EMBLE   LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF    2017
A3      TUBO    ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF    2017
A4      PRESI   ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF    2017
A5      PARA    ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF    2017
A6      AR      ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF    2017
A7      PRESI   ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF    2017
A8      CILI    CABE    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF    2017
```

Arquivo2.csv

```
Codigo  Nome    Catego  Geral                   Model   Ano
A1      JOGO    LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51    2018
A2      EMBLE   LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51    2018
B1      CHAVE   LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51    2018
B2      CHAVE   LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51    2018
B3      MANU    LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51    2018
B4      AMOR    LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51    2018
B5      GUIA    CABE    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51    2018
```

Arquivo3.csv

```
Codigo  Nome    Catego  Geral                   Model   Ano
A8      CILI    CABE    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC54    2021
B5      GUIA    CABE    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC54    2021
C1      ANEL    CABE    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC54    2021
C2      PARA    CABE    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC54    2021
A6      AR      ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC54    2021
A7      PRESI   ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC54    2021
A3      TUBO    ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC54    2021
B2      CHAV    LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC54    2021
```

Fiz algo assim:

```py
import tabula 
import tabulate
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import csvs
import ssl
from tabula import read_pdf
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
primeiro = pd.read_csv('/content/Arquivo1.csv')
segundo = pd.read_csv('/content/Arquivo2.csv')
terceiro = pd.read_csv('/content/Arquivo3.csv')
df = pd.merge(primeiro, segundo, on='Codigo', how='outer') # Aqui faço algo do tipo PROCV
df ['Model'] = df ['Model_x']. map(str) + ' | ' + df ['Model_y']. map(str) # Aqui concateno coluna Model
df ['Ano'] = df ['Ano_x']. map(str) + ' | ' + df ['Ano_y']. map(str) # Aqui concateno coluna Ano
df.drop('Model_x', axis=1, inplace=True) # Deleto o que sobrou
df.drop('Ano_x', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop('Model_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop('Ano_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.to_csv (r'/content/Junta.csv', index = False, header = True, encoding='cp1252', na_rep = 'NaN') # Salvo
somados = pd.read_csv('/content/Junta.csv') # Leio trocando para somados
df = pd.merge(somados, terceiro, on='Codigo', how='outer') # Repito tudo de novo
df ['Model'] = df ['Model_x']. map(str) + ' | ' + df ['Model_y']. map(str)
df ['Ano'] = df ['Ano_x']. map(str) + ' | ' + df ['Ano_y']. map(str)
df.drop('Model_x', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop('Ano_x', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop('Model_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop('Ano_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.to_csv (r'/content/Junta3.csv', index = False, header = True, encoding='cp1252', na_rep = 'NaN')
df
```

Se você fizer isso vai obter o seguinte resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o resultado correto é deslocar as quadros vermelhos da imagem e depois apagar tudo que ficou no amarelo, veja no detalhe na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o resultado correto é o mostrado abaixo.
Então como faço para obter este resultado abaixo:

Arquivo Junta3.csv

```
Codigo  Nome    Catego  Geral                   Model       Ano
A1      JOGO    LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF|BC51   2017|2018
A2      EMBLE   LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF|BC51   2017|2018
A3      TUBO    ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF|BC54   2017|2021
A4      PRESI   ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF        2017
A5      PARA    ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF        2017
A6      AR      ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF|BC54   2017|2021
A7      PRESI   ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF|BC54   2017|2021
A8      CILI    CABE    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    44CF|BC54   2017|2021
B1      CHAVE   LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51        2018
B2      CHAVE   LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51|BC54    2018|2021
B3      MANU    LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51        2018
B4      AMOR    LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51        2018
B5      GUIA    CABE    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC51|BC54   2018|2021
C1      ANEL    CABE    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC54        2021
C2      PARA    CABE    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB    BC54        2021
```

Por favor, o desafio é grande, em Excel já fiz e deu certo, então quer dizer que usando Python com Pandas também é possível, quem puder ajudar agradeço

Comment: Poderia detalhar qual é o critério que usa para unir as três tabelas?

Comment: Acreito que você esta procurando pelo comando [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: @LuizNotari, entendi a finalidade, mas eu quero saber especificamente o lado prático da atividade. O que o algoritmo deve fazer? Ao encontrar duas `chaves` iguais exemplo `A1` os campos `Nome`, `Catego` e `Geral` terão sempre os mesmos valores nas três tabelas ou não?  Somente os campos `Model` e `Ano` serão concatenado com `|` ou tem alguma outra consideração? O problema é simples, mas precisamos das especificações exatas pois a hora que jogar o código nos seus dados o algoritmo pode encontrar algo inesperado e falhar.

Comment: Luiz Notari, não rasure as perguntas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha proposta de solução envolve o uso das funções `concat`, `groupby`, `map` e `drop_duplicates`. 
Primeiro faça a união de todos os seus arquivos com `concat`, com o `groupby` por **Codigo** concatene as strings das colunas **Ano** e **Model**, com o `map` recrie as colunas **Ano** e **Model** com todos os valores encontrados no `groupby` e por fim, use o `drop_duplicates` para excluir ocorrências duplicadas.

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], ignore_index = True)
df['Ano'] = df["Ano"].astype('str')

d = df.groupby('Codigo').agg(
                              Ano = ('Ano', lambda x: '|'.join(x)),
                              Model = ('Model', lambda x: '|'.join(x))
                            )
df['Ano'] = df['Codigo'].map(d['Ano'])
df['Model'] = df['Codigo'].map(d['Model'])
df = df.drop_duplicates()

#resultado
df.head()
       Codigo   Nome   Catego  Geral                 Model      Ano
0      A1       JOGO   LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB  44CF|BC51  2017|2018
1      A2       EMBLE  LAMA    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB  44CF|BC51  2017|2018
2      A3       TUBO   ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB  44CF|BC54  2017|2021
3      A4       PRESI  ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB  44CF       2017
4      A5       PARA   ADMI    FZ25-A|YS250|FA250AB  44CF       2017
```

Comment: @LuizNotari Caso minha resposta tenha sido satisfatória, por favor, considere aceita-la. Isso é importante pois deixa claro aos demais usuários que seu problema está resolvido. No link [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/30452) mostra como faze-lo :)